# No errors are returned when exception occurs, instead I get No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: php, laravel, cors

I already posted the similar question to another thread, the reason I re posted it is that I got into problem deeper and can explain it more.

**Actual Problem**: I am using a library from **barryvdh/laravel-cors** and when an **error/exception** happens this library does not set the **headers** and it keep saying No '**Access-Control-Allow-Origin**' header is present on the requested resource.

Let say I have a simple function like this:

```
public function store(Request $request){
    return response()->json(['message' => 'coming without any problem']);
}
```

which works perfectly fine, and I have the other case with syntax error:

```
public function store(Request $request){
    return response()->json(['message' => 'coming with problem'); // missing ']' before the end parenthesis....
}
```

This should normally throw an exception by Laravel, but for me it shows '**Access-Control-Allow-Origin**'.

Well, you might ask, why do I need this to fix, is that when my code is more complex, I dont see the actuall error that will help me to fix it or at least google it...

Anyone had the same issue before and have any idea how to fix this thing?
I am using Laravel 5.0

Comment: Where does it show 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'? Does it just show on the webpage? Because something seems to be requiring that header to be set.

Comment: it shows on the console line in browser Chrome...

Answer (score 2):

This has to do with "cross-origin HTTP request" that can be a mix of front end and backend issues.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

You may need to change some settings in your web server settings or on your .htaccess file located in the script folder.

Check this: http://enable-cors.org/server.html

In terms of front end, Mozilla tends to be a little more conservative about CORS, so check their docs. If you do it well for firefox, it will work well on other browsers too.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: I have followed all of those tutorials and still I cant fix, this seems from my prespective more like problem with the barryvdh/laravel-cors library.

There is no CORS issue happens in any request when no exception happens... only when an exception happens it shows origin error

Comment: Do a quick test adding this line to your .htaccess file: 

Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

Comment: I did added it, this actually makes it even worse, showing XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://theventuregame.com/new/venture-backend/public/users/645. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values